# Libaries folder is empty in xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native

I've been working on the project for two months. The Libraries folder became empty in Xcode as seen in the picture. Where are my linking packages? Is it deleted or invisible?

[image]

Comment: Have you got the answer? I'm also stuck in that place.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Having the same issue, how can you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue and managed to fix it by linking the framework via the library itself, rather then adding it via the general settings. The framework I was trying to link was located under `<project-name>/Frameworks` in the project-navigator. Here I was able to link it to the proper target by checking the proper instance under `Target Membership` on the right-side of the screen. After cleaning the build folder I managed to build my project again.

Answer (score -1):

After RN 0.60 all Libraries can support pods. You have to open .xcworkspace then .xcodeproj. and you can see all Libraries in pod folder.